# PHP JSON 2 dimensional array output

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I've been stuck here for about 2 hours and I need some help.

**What I'm trying to accomplish**

I have a MySQL DB which has a table called `movies` and has rows such as `question`, `answer`, `category`. Where the category is important. Since each category should be printed as it's own array, with rows that has the value of that category.

So all rows with category `Two and a Half Men` should display in the `Two and a Half Men` array beneath.

**Example:**

```
[
  {
    "Arrow": [
      "question:","this is a question"
      "answer","this is an answer"
    ],
    "How I Met Your Mother": [
      "question:","this is a question"
      "answer","this is an answer"
    ],
    "South Park": [
      "question:","this is a question"
      "answer","this is an answer"
    ],
    "The Big Bang Theory": [
      "question:","this is a question"
      "answer","this is an answer"
    ],
    "The Last Man On Earth": [
      "question:","this is a question"
      "answer","this is an answer"
    ]
  }
]
```

**What I have as JSON output:**

```
[
  {
    "Arrow": [
      "question without the key value(only the string..)"
    ],
    "How I Met Your Mother": [
      "question without the key value(only the string..)"
    ],
    "South Park": [
      "question without the key value(only the string..)"
    ],
    "The Big Bang Theory": [
      "question without the key value(only the string..)"
    ],
    "The Last Man On Earth": [
      "question without the key value(only the string..)"
    ],
    "Two and a Half Men": [
      ""
    ]
  }
]
```

**My code:**

```
<?php

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM movies";


if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
  $category = array();

  while($thearray = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    // this is the part where it gets messy. ->
    // more columns should show such as question, while the category is only the array.
      $category[$thearray['category']] = [$thearray['question']];

      array_push($category);

  }

  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode(array($category));


}

// Close connections
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

*Sincerely, Jimmie!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append a new element to the category array dynamically with `[]`. You should use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` to get only the column names as indexes.  Also, if you want all of the columns that were selected, then just use all of `$thearray`:

```
while($thearray = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $category[$thearray['category']][] = $thearray;
}
```

Or for specific columns:

```
$category[$thearray['category']][] = ['question' => $thearray['question'],
                                      'answer' => $thearray['answer']];
```

Comment: Alright, your second one worked. How it looks now: https://gyazo.com/6612f52889a9e0ff958250bdae67c041

But how can I add the key value? I believe something like [$thearray['Question'=>'question']], but that didnt work :/

Comment: Thanks btw, your small change of my piece of code was greatly functional. Many thanks!

Comment: That should cover the bases.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much for the help! Happy coding mate :')